# Adding tool tips to menu items and views

Tags: views, 6, routes, tooltips

I need to add tool tips to some of the primary links in my menus, and also to a link in a view, I tried to use the [Tool Tips](http://drupal.org/project/tooltips) module, but it doesn't seem to be designed for this kind of use... is there another module I can use, or is there another way I can integrate tips to my dynamic content?

Comment: Do you need fancy tooltips, or just hover text on links for accessibility reasons?

Comment: just hover text to offer the user some additional info...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [qTip module](http://drupal.org/project/qtip) or the [Tipsy module](http://drupal.org/project/tipsy) as alternatives to get "good looking" tooltips or simply add a description to the menu items for basic browser created tooltips

Answer (score -1):

[Beautytips](https://drupal.org/project/beautytips) would do the trick, I think:

> The Beautytips module provides ballon-help style tooltips for any page
>   element by integrating the BeautyTips jQuery Tooltip plugin by Jeff
>   Robbins with Drupal. It provides an API for adding custom beautytips
>   as well as some built-in features. Admins can enable rollover
>   balloon-help style tooltips for text fields within forms. It also
>   supplies hover tips for Drupal help links and advanced help links.

The module page has a very nice video to achieve what you need